Interaction to next paint and consent
How Google PageSpeed Test and Lighthouse measure INP, while the most sites are behind consent opt-in? What concretely is measured there?
In my understanding, before consent opt-in is granted, a site doesn't offer any kind of interaction, beside of click on consent banner.
Could somebody explain it?

Google PageSpeed Insights and Google Search Console both source INP as measured by the Chrome User Experience Report (CrUX). This measures data based on opt ins at a browser-level, rather than individual site-level. After that anonymised, aggregated data is made public.
The included user criteria for Chrome users are listed in the documentation:

User
For a user to have their experiences aggregated in the CrUX dataset, they must meet the following criteria:

Enable usage statistic reporting.
Sync their browser history.
Not have a Sync passphrase set.
Use a supported platform.

The current supported platforms are:
Desktop versions of Chrome including Windows, macOS, ChromeOS, and Linux operating systems.
Android versions of Chrome, including mobile apps using Custom Tabs and WebAPKs.
There are a few notable exceptions that don't provide data to the CrUX dataset:

Chrome on iOS.
Android apps using WebView.
Other Chromium browsers (for example Microsoft Edge).


"In my understanding, before consent opt-in is granted, a site doesn't offer any kind of interaction, beside of click on consent banner. Could somebody explain it?"
User can ignore the opt-ins and still interaction with a page depending on whether the consent banner is one of the types that cover the page or not. Additionally the acceptance of consent itself can be trigger a large amount of work, which is often the cause of INP.
